# Fluentd <Secondary> Functionality Issue

Tags: fluentd

I'm having a problem with a Fluentd configuration that I haven't been able to solve and was wondering if someone might be able to help me or point me in the right direction.

I have Fluentd(v1.15.3) installed on a Rocky Linux(v8.7) server.  The log events that this Fluentd instance receives are ultimately indexed into an Elasticsearch(v7.4.2) environment.

I'm trying to setup a Fluentd configuration where log events that do not get successfully processed by the Elasticsearch output plugin(i.e. unsuccessful index requests) are stored in a directory for further manual analysis.  I'm trying to use the `<secondary>` element for this but it doesn't seem to be working in my configuration and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Here is the Fluentd configuration(sensitive information has been replaced with placeholders):

```
<source>
  @type forward
  tag standard_log
</source>

<match standard_log>
  @log_level trace
  @type elasticsearch
  hosts <List Elasticsearch host:port entries>
  scheme https
  ssl_verify true
  ca_file <CA File Path>
  user <User>
  password ******
  index_name <Index Name>
  <buffer>
    @type file
    path <Path>/calyptia-fluentd/elasticsearch_output_plugin/buffer
    flush_mode interval
    flush_interval 30s
    retry_timeout 10s
    retry_max_times 1
  </buffer>
  <secondary>
    @type secondary_file
    directory <Path>/calyptia-fluentd/elasticsearch_output_plugin/errors
  </secondary>
</match>
```

When a log event is not processed by the Elasticsearch output plugin successfully(i.e. the index request fails), what I want is for the log event to be stored in the `<Path>/calyptia-fluentd/elasticsearch_output_plugin/errors` directory.  However, that doesn't seem to be happening and I have been unable to figure out why.

Here is a snippet of the Fluentd log when a log event was not processed by the Elasticsearch output plugin successfully(sensitive information has again been replaced with placeholders):

```
2023-12-04 23:05:41 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:41 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:44 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:44 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:45 -0500 [info]: #1 disable filter chain optimization because [Fluent::Plugin::ConcatFilter, Fluent::Plugin::RecordTransformerFilter] uses `#filter_stream` method.
2023-12-04 23:05:45 -0500 [trace]: #1 writing events into buffer instance=2420 metadata_size=1
2023-12-04 23:05:45 -0500 [debug]: #1 Created new chunk chunk_id="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845" metadata=#<struct Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::Metadata timekey=nil, tag="standard_log", variables=nil, seq=0>
2023-12-04 23:05:45 -0500 [trace]: #1 chunk <Path>/calyptia-fluentd/elasticsearch_output_plugin/buffer/worker1/buffer.b60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845.log size_added: 1336 new_size: 1336
2023-12-04 23:05:47 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:47 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:49 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:49 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:52 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:52 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:55 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:55 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:58 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:05:58 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:00 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:00 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:03 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:03 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:06 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:06 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:09 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:09 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:11 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:11 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:14 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:14 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing chunk instance=2420 metadata=#<struct Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::Metadata timekey=nil, tag="standard_log", variables=nil, seq=0>
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 dequeueing a chunk instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 chunk dequeued instance=2420 metadata=#<struct Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::Metadata timekey=nil, tag="standard_log", variables=nil, seq=0>
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 trying flush for a chunk chunk="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845"
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 adding write count instance=2400
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 executing sync write chunk="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845"
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 bulk request: {"index":{"_index":"<Index Name>","_type":"_doc"}}
{<Elasticsearch Document>}

2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 bulk response: {"took"=>34, "errors"=>true, "items"=>[{"index"=>{"_index"=>"<Index Name>", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"<ID>", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [<Field>] of type [<Type>] in document with id '<ID>'. Preview of field's value: '<Value>'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse <Type> field [<Value>] with format [<Format>]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"<Type>_parse_exception", "reason"=>"<Type>_parse_exception: Text '<Text>' could not be parsed at index 19"}}}}}]}
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [warn]: #1 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchErrorHandler::ElasticsearchError error="400 - Rejected by Elasticsearch [error type]: mapper_parsing_exception [reason]: 'failed to parse field [<Field>] of type [<Type>] in document with id '<ID>'. Preview of field's value: '<Value>''" location=nil tag="standard_log" time=2023-12-04 23:05:45.826817561 -0500 record={<Record>}
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [debug]: #1 Indexed (op = index), 1 bad_argument
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 write operation done, committing chunk="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845"
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 committing write operation to a chunk chunk="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845" delayed=false
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 purging a chunk instance=2420 chunk_id="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845" metadata=#<struct Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::Metadata timekey=nil, tag="standard_log", variables=nil, seq=0>
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 chunk purged instance=2420 chunk_id="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845" metadata=#<struct Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::Metadata timekey=nil, tag="standard_log", variables=nil, seq=0>
2023-12-04 23:06:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 done to commit a chunk chunk="60bbb595577e358b88957f98f24e6845"
2023-12-04 23:06:19 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:19 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:22 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:22 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:25 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:25 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:28 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:28 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:30 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:30 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:33 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:33 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:36 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:36 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:39 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:39 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:41 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:41 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:44 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:44 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:47 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:47 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:49 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:49 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:52 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:52 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:55 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:55 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:58 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:06:58 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:00 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:00 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:03 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:03 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:06 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:06 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:09 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:09 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:11 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:11 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:14 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:14 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:17 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:17 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:19 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:19 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:22 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:22 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:25 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:25 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:28 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:28 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:30 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:30 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:33 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:33 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:36 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:36 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:39 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:39 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:41 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:41 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:44 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:44 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:47 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:47 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:49 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:49 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:52 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:52 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:55 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:55 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:58 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:07:58 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:08:00 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:08:00 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:08:03 -0500 [trace]: #1 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
2023-12-04 23:08:03 -0500 [trace]: #0 enqueueing all chunks in buffer instance=2420
```

Looking at the log, if I'm reading it correctly it appears that Fluentd is treating the log event as being successfully processed even though the index request to Elasticsearch failed.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: So upon further analysis, it looks like the log event will only get stored or routed to the location specified in the <secondary> section if the Elasticsearch output plugin cannot connect to Elasticsearch.  As long as it can connect to Elasticsearch, it will not store or route the log event to the <secondary> location even if the index request fails.  A little disappointing but it is what it is.